# How to use clusterProperties in mapbox-gl

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I built a mapbox-gl js (v0.52) map where points are getting aggregated into clusters; much like in the [clusters example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/) from mapbox page.

The cluster color needs to be a function of an aggregation of individual points properties: For simplicity, say each point has a `status` property, which determine its color, and the color of a cluster should just be the color corresponding to the `max` of each of its points' `status` values.

Example geojson data would look like:

```
const geoData = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {
        id: 'fakeid11',
        status: 20,
      },
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-151.5129, 63.1016, 0]
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {
        id: 'fakeid22',
        status: 10,
      },
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-150.4048, 63.1224, 105.5]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I am trying to use `clusterProperties` to compute the aggregation as [described in the api docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-geojson-clusterProperties), similar to [this example from the source code](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/debug/cluster.html#L35), to create this layer:

```
map.addSource('earthquakes', {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: geoData,
  cluster: true,
  clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
  clusterRadius: 50, // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
  clusterProperties: {
    status: ['max', ['get', 'status']]
  }
});
```

This snippet is exactly like the clusters example from mapbox page, just replacing the data by my static 2-elements copy, and adding `clusterProperties`.

However this throws a validation error (a bit mangled from the minified mapbox-gl version):

```
Error: sources.earthquakes: unknown property "clusterProperties"
    at Object.Jr [as emitValidationErrors] (modules.js?hash=34588b9e7240c1a9b3fd2f8685e299d9dbbb40d9:504146)
    at De (modules.js?hash=34588b9e7240c1a9b3fd2f8685e299d9dbbb40d9:504150)
    at i._validate (modules.js?hash=34588b9e7240c1a9b3fd2f8685e299d9dbbb40d9:504150)
```

What is wrong with this `clusterProperties` usage? It would seem it is simply refusing to validate this property. Note that the map works ok (without the `status` aggregated property of course) if I comment the last 3 lines that set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer days later: The version of react-map-gl we were using had dependency on mapbox-gl `~0.52.0`, which did not yet support `clusterProperties`. Support for these aggregated properties comes in mapbox-gl 0.53. (And since the react wrapper uses undocumented features of mapbox-gl, they depend on exact versions at patch level). This was [confirmed by the react library developers](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/issues/737).

Now react-map-gl 4.0.14 is released and it works ok with `clusterProperties`, using internally mapbox-gl 0.53.0.